# I'm attempting an "updateMany" statement in MongoDb to update rows in this table, and get an "Unexpected token" message. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, syntax-error

Here is the MongoDb table:
['email_status' collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MmFa.png)

and here is my attempt at using the "updateMany" command:

```
db.getCollection('email_status').updateMany({
   SentOn: {
       $gte: ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
       $lt: ISODate("2023-10-31T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    "EmailMessage.ReplyAddress.Address": {$eq: "testaccount@mailinator.com"},
    $set: {EmailMessage.ReplyAddress.Address: "support@mycompany.org", EmailMessage.ReplyAddress.DisplayName: "My Name"}
    })
```

I've tried modifying the **$set:** statement many different ways but still not getting a working update statement.

This is the error I am getting with the code above:

```
Error: Line 7: Unexpected token .
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

- You must enclose field names in quotes if they contain a dot (.)
- The `$eq` is not needed (you can use it, but it is extra writing)
- You missed a curly bracket to separate **filter** and **update**:

  `db.collection.updateMany(filter, update, options)`

Would be this like this one:

```
db.getCollection('email_status').updateMany(
   {
      SentOn: {
         $gte: ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
         $lt: ISODate("2023-10-31T00:00:00.000Z")
      },
      "EmailMessage.ReplyAddress.Address": "testaccount@mailinator.com"
   },
   {
      $set: {
         "EmailMessage.ReplyAddress.Address": "support@mycompany.org",
         "EmailMessage.ReplyAddress.DisplayName": "My Name"
      }
   }
)
```